# Calling VueLoaderPlugin() causes 'findIndex' undefined error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to integrate a Vue CLI app in another web project we are working with. The Vue app itself works when running the dev server bundled with Vue CLI.

The Vue application contains `.vue` files, so a loader for webpack is needed. I used the setup from the [vue-loader documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#vue-cli). When I ran webpack (via Grunt) I now get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined Use --force to continue.
```

After a lot of tinkering I figured out that the `new VueLoaderPlugin();` line from the documentation mentioned above was the cause of this. However I do need this plugin to get my .vue-files to work.

I am using the following set of loaders, imported using npm via package.json:

```
{
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    //...
    "webpack": "~3.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
}
```

I have tried googling for the error but came up empty handed. All help and suggestions are welcome. Cheers!

Comment: I think I might be on to something here. I found a typo in the ```webpack.config.js``` file, causing the module.rules to be undefined. I think that might be it. 

Will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fiddling around trying to get the `vue-loader` to work, at some point I got an error leading me to update webpack to a later version. This version seemed to have deprecated the use of `module.loaders` in favour of `module.rules`.

Changing this in the webpack config seems to have made everything work smoothly. Hope someone finds this useful!